# IE fieldset rendering

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a form in an HTML page, works great in all browsers except IE.  I know it has something with IE rendering the fieldset tag, and I have tried using a psuedo div to hack it, but that did not work.  Anybody run across this or have a work around?
Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/G9NSx/
&
Here's the code:

```
        <form>
                    <fieldset>
                    <ol>
                        <li>
                            <label for="name">Name<em> *</em></label>
                            <input id="name" />
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label for="company">Company Name</label>
                            <input id="company" />
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label for="address">Address</label>
                            <input id="address" />
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label for="city">City</label>
                            <input id="city" />
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label for="state">State/Providence</label>
                            <input id="state" />
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label for="country">Country</label>
                            <input id="country" />
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label for="phone">Phone<em> *</em></label>
                            <input id="phone" />
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label for="fax">Fax</label>
                            <input id="fax" />
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label for="email">Email</label>
                            <input id="email" />
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <fieldset class="regarding">
                                <legend>Regarding:<em> *</em></legend>
                                    <label><input type="radio" name="regarding" /> Capabilities</label>
                                    <label><input type="radio" name="regarding" /> Testing Information</label>
                                    <label><input type="radio" name="regarding" /> Business Relations</label>
                                    <label><input type="radio" name="regarding" /> Other</label>
                            </fieldset>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label for="add-info">Additional Info.</label><br />
                            <textarea name="add-info"></TEXTAREA>
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit"> <input type="reset" value="Reset"/><br />
                        <br />
                        <span class="bold">Required Fields<em> *</em></span>
                    </fieldset>
            </form>
```

CSS:

```
form {
    border: 1px solid #0066FF;
    /*background-image: url(../images/form-bg.jpg);*/
    background-color: #FFF;
}

form fieldset {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
}

form legend {
    padding: 0 2px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

form label {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 1.8;
    vertical-align: top;
}

form fieldset ol {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

form fieldset li {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0;
}

form fieldset li textarea {
    min-width: 300px;
    max-width: 500px;
    }

form fieldset fieldset {
    border: none;
    margin: 3px 0 0;
}

form fieldset fieldset legend {
    padding: 0 0 5px;
    font-weight: normal;
}

form fieldset fieldset label {
    display: block;
    width: auto;
}

form em {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
    color: #0066FF;
}

form label {
    width: 120px; /* Width of labels */
}

form fieldset fieldset label {
    margin-left: 123px; /* Width plus 3 (html space) */
}

form fieldset ol li fieldset.regarding {
    padding: 0px;
    }
```

Here is a screenshot of the issue I am having in IE9
[image]

Comment: You have not specified what you regard as wrong in rendering on IE (which version(s) in which mode(s))? The jsfiddle looks pretty much the same on IE 9 as on Firefox; at least I cannot see any *obvious* problem.

Comment: I added a screenshot, for some reason jsFiddle does looks fine?

Comment: @Ben p crap, i think i just overwrote your fiddle, gimme a minute Ill restore it back to your state, apologies.

Comment: No worries @Sajjan I appreciate the feedback, I'm going to see if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be one of odd bugs in IE 9. To circumvent it, add an empty `div` element, i.e. `<div></div>` before the `form` element. And the problem will probably go away automatically when you put the form onto a real page that has some content before it, like a heading.

Every now and then, IE does odd things with forms that appear at the very start of a document, or with elements that appear at the very start of a form. If you inspect the page on IE 9 (using F12), you can see that the problem only appears in “standards mode” (!), not in quirks (compatibility) mode. And style settings are largely lost.

Comment: Ah, thanks @Jukka.  I tried adding the pseudo div, but I was putting it before the fieldset.  This worked, I appreciate your feedback!

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose of the outer fieldset? It lacks the legend tag. You could do without it (but then need to rewrite your CSS). While nested fieldsets are not a problem in IE according to my experience, you don't need the added markup and styling complexity unless all fieldsets have a legend.

Next time you could put your code in a fiddle for faster and more acurate answers.

Comment: Good points, but not an answer; it should have been posted as a comment.

Comment: Thanks, will do that next time.

Answer (score 0):

Added this CSS class, see if this is what you wanted to achieve

```
fieldset, img, .regarding{
 border-width: 1px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:red;
}
```

updated the fiddlehttp://jsfiddle.net/9F2eB/

I know this is not the ideal "highly optimized" way of writing, but if this is the desired effect you want to produce, take idea and run away with it.